# enable/disable a job in quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I want to disable a quartz job for a given period of time. Though we can use pauseJob/resumeJob, but the catch is on resumeJob it fires all the missed triggers(Yes, I don't want to change the default mis-fire policy, so that even if someone provides past time, job still runs).

Is there a way where we can disable a job for certain time, and on enabling it back it should NOT fire any missed triggers.

Comment: Is deleting (or unscheduling) the job and rescheduling it somehting acceptable for you ?

Comment: If I delete the job, I have to persist job and its trigger information explicitly, which I want to avoid.
There can be other solutions on similar line, but all of them requires keeping explicit data. I was looking for something out of the box.

Comment: Then I think your best option is to use pause/resume with a custom misfire policy, even if you don't wish to change it...